# netlify-cms git commits are not showing up on website

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I spun up a jamstack website using gatsby-cms template. I set the domain name, ssl, and made my first posts using the admin interface. The posts showup in the git repository and it shows that the site has been modified in the netlify dashboard but the changes don't show up on the site.

Is an additional step for deploying changes to the site?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because isn't yet authenticated or given permission by whatever git repositories you used. Have you enable your page identity? See here https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/authentication-backends/ or Here https://www.netlify.com/docs/identity/

Comment: I don't need to setup page identity as I am add posts through the admin console on the website itself.

Comment: "Admin Console"  Could you elaborate? If you want to see content of posts you generate with Netlify CMS through your page. You will need to enable identity as it authenticate with your git repository to update the changes.

Comment: You know the /admin page for the site itself(not on netlify). I post everything there and it doesn't show updates to the site itself. The identity thing is for managing accounts.

Comment: " /admin page for the site itself(not on netlify)" 
so, where did you deploy your page into?